# Is it faster to loop through a Python set of number or a set of letters?

Tags: python, algorithm, list, set

Is it faster to loop through a Python `set` of numbers or a Python `set` of letters given that each set is the exact same length and each item within each set is the same length? Why?

I would think that there would be a difference because letters have more possible characters [a-zA-Z] than numbers [0-9] and therefor would be more 'random' and likely affect the hashing to some extent.

```
numbers = set([00000,00001,00002,00003,00004,00005, ... 99999])

letters = set(['aaaaa','aaaab','aaaac','aaaad', ... 'aaabZZ']) # this is just an example, it does not actually end here

for item in numbers:
  do_something()

for item in letters:
  do_something()
```

where len(numbers) == len(letters)

**Update**: I am interested in Python's specific hashing algorithm and what happens behind the scenes with this implementation.

Comment: An md5 hash is an md5 hash - it's precisely the same action regardless of the content to be hashed (provided the length of input is the constant) It should make no difference how random the data is to how quick the hashing is. That's one of the main advantages of hashing, in fact - a constant exec time for any given length of input data.

Comment: It could be a bit faster to loop through set of numbers, because element of numbers is using less memory

Comment: @enhzflep: Python doesn't use MD5 as the hash function for numbers *or* for strings. This may be out of date, but it describes the hash functions used at one point: http://effbot.org/zone/python-hash.htm

Comment: @SteveJessop -thanks for the link. I didn't expect (nor claim) that it did. I understand that I may be seen as having implied that. Interesting that they call the function applied to ints a hash function. So reading your link, it seems that 'hashing' a number should be vastly faster than hashing a string or tuple. Returning a number has to beat a multiply _per character_ in the string, right?

Comment: Why don't you time it and see?

Comment: @enhzflep: you'd expect so, although the difference isn't necessarily big -- the string hash is computed in C code, and although slower than the int hash it might not be slow enough (for shortish strings) to really be noticeable compared with the other costs of a hash insertion or lookup. It's pretty common across programming languages for hashtables to use that "hash function" for integers. Clearly it is not a hash in the cryptographic sense, neither is it a useful checksum. It's merely a way of turning data into an index to use in a hashtable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There might be some particular implementation details of Python that I'm not aware of that mess with my general arguments here, but:

- *Creating* the set of strings will likely be a little slower than creating the set of integers (all else being equal), since the hash operation on strings takes some (small) time to run while the hash operation on integers is trivial.
- *Iterating* a set doesn't perform any hash operations, so the time to hash is irrelevant there.
- Iterating a set depends on the number of elements in the set and the number of buckets in the hash table backing the set. So the distribution of the hash function only matters if it causes the hash table to increase the bucket count. For some hash table implementations that's impossible (because bucket count is only increased when the load factor exceeds a threshold, not just because of collisions). Other hash table implementations resize when there are a lot of collisions. I don't know which CPython is.
- Anyway, the particular example you give of a set of integers will generate well-distributed hash values.
- There's one way to find out which is faster in Python, which is to `timeit`, with a realistic example of the data you care about. Speculation is usually a waste of time.

You can see the results of Python's hashing algorithms like this:

```
>>> foo = 3
>>> foo.__hash__()
3
>>> foo = 1856348
>>> foo.__hash__()
1856348
>>> foo = "\x00"
>>> foo.__hash__()
1
>>> foo = "\x01"
>>> foo.__hash__()
128000384
>>> foo = "\x02"
>>> foo.__hash__()
256000771
```

So on my copy of Python, those hash results match these [reported Python hash algorithms](http://effbot.org/zone/python-hash.htm). As ever with CPython, you can look at the source to confirm the algorithm.

Comment: +1 nice points, I like this approach more than looking at random data like I did.  Without knowledge of exactly what op is trying to do, everything really is speculation.

Comment: The downside of random data is that (assuming Python uses plausible hash functions), it pretty much ensures even distribution of hashes. So even if the questioner is correct that *his* data produces uneven hashing, a test with random data would obscure that effect. But by doing so it would separate that effect from any other effects on timing, so it's still useful in combination with other timings.

Answer (score 2):

You can't know until you profile!  Here's some crude data:

```
% python -mtimeit -s 'import string;import random;s=set("".join(random.sample(string.printable, 5))for _ in range(10000))' 'for foo in s: bar=foo'
1000 loops, best of 3: 376 usec per loop

% python -mtimeit -s 'import random;s=set(int("".join(map(str,random.sample(range(10),5))))for _ in range(10000))' 'for foo in s: bar=foo'                     
1000 loops, best of 3: 322 usec per loop
```

It looks like you're correct that there is a slight difference, but you'd need to do a lot more testing to say much with confidence.